# CSRF vulnerability & multiple instances of my Node.js backend in the cloud

Tags: node.js, csrf, csrf-protection

Learning about CSRF attacks leads me to secure a Nodejs app. It's currently running in the cloud. Multiple instances of the server are running and it's made transparent by the cloud host provider.

My understanding of securing an app against CSRF:

- Make POST handlers expect a "data-token".
- The data-token is server-side generated and cannot be tampered (hashing with secret)
- The data-token is generated for a given resource and is refused on other routes.
- The data-token must expire (or "burn") after its first use.

What's the usual way to handle the data-token? I had the following in mind:

- store the tokens in a shared database?

  - clean the database from expired & burnt tokens

Answer (score 1):

If the token is generated and hashed server-side, you could just pass them to the client and then retrieve them server-side without storing them in a database. I think the `Json Web Token` authentication principle could give you some ideas.

In my mind, you encrypt a json object with the limit timestamp server-side, pass it to the client, the client sends it back to your server when posting the form, you uncrypt it (only you can do it with the secret) and PUFF ! you retrieve your original data.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. Indeed, the JWT is in use for authentication. However, the solution to CSRF implies to issue a token that can only be used once. Multiple instances of the server must have a mechanism to stay in sync regarding the valid tokens circulating.

Comment: @Jem a CSRF token does not necessarily need to be one-time-use, nor does it have to be valid for only one resource. While making both of those things true is the Most Secure (TM), this requires storing info in a DB, which might not scale. It's not invalid for your CSRF token validity and expiration to be tied to your auth token in such a way that it is stateless. (eg, if your auth token is JWT, add a claim that is the key to decrypt the CSRF token.)